# changing html output with js

Tags: javascript, html, css

i'm quite new to js and i know i'm taking something difficult on. the tl;dr would be that i'm trying to make a simple GUI to learn js better and what i'm looking for it's a bit of guidance

so i have this code

`

Name: {nameSource}

Class: {charClassSource}

Level: {levelSource}

```
<li><dt class="padt">Primary Attribute:</dt><dl class="padl"> {primaryAttributeSource}  </dl></li>
<li><dt class="secdt">Secondary Attribute:</dt><dl class="secdl"> {secondaryAttributeSource}  </dl></li>
```

```
<li><dt class="atidt1">{AttributeItem1} </dt><dl class="atidl1"> {AttributeItem1Source}  </dl></li>
<li><dt class="atidt2">{AttributeItem2} </dt><dl class="atidl2"> {AttributeItem2Source}  </dl></li>
<li><dt class="atidt3">{AttributeItem3} </dt><dl class="atidl3"> {AttributeItem2Source}  </dl></li>
```

Now what i need to know not to bother too much is that depending on the Primary At and Secondary the Source would change. For example if you have 10 Strength + 5 from items your Primary Attribute would be 15.
The others doesn't really matter right know I'd only need some help with the basic ones.

`

Nothing that I tried  too much since I am a bit new to js. Probably I'd try to target the dl class="padl" to replace the content with the sum of the let strength = "15" for eg  but since i am new i don't know exactly how to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this might be homework, since you are given a problem and asked to find a solution, but don't really know how to start.

Start with the small stuff and work your way up. I googled "javascript find replace" and clicked the first google result: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_replace

You can edit this code and see how "find and replace" works in Javascript. Once you understand that concept and how the JS code actually works, you can apply it to the HTML you were provided. Perhaps replace `{AttributeItem1}` with `Hello!` to start.

Then you can google "javascript add two numbers together" to learn how math works in JS, and work that into your existing find-and-replace code.

If this is homework, make sure you are reading the assigned sections in the textbook/materials that your teacher assigned. Likely these concepts are covered in the lecture materials.

Comment: Thank you good sir and yes that's what i was looking for. Appreciate it <3